# Zend Framework - module routing

Tags: zend-framework

I have a module called users. Inside I have an index controller, with an action called part1Action() inside the index controller class.

I expected to be able to access the part1Action() action through the path /user/index/part1, but I'm ending up in the /user/index/index action.

I have other modules set up that are working from a module/controller point of view, but I've not tried accessing other actions apart from the index action in these, so this is the first time I've tried routing to other than the index action.

More info, I have this in my application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules = ""
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Users_"
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*part1Action* is not going to be a valid Action name as it contains a number. Name the action something like *partOneAction*. If you absolutely want to use a number in your url set up a routing rule like so

```
$front->getRouter()->addRoute(
    'part-1',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
        '/user/index/part1/',
        array('module' => 'users', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'part-one')
    )
);
```

Honestly though, I would probably set my module up a little differently. I'm assuming that this is for a multi-page form of some kind?

so:

```
modules
    user
        controllers
            {some-meaningful-name}Controller.php
```

inside of {some-meaningful-controller-name}Controller.php

```
    public function {some-meaningful-action-name}Action()
    {
        $part = $this->getRequest()->getParam('part', 1);
    }
```

that way your url would be

```
/user/{some-meaningful-controller-name}/{some-meaningful-action-name}/part/{some-number}
```

Comment: OK, I'm still missing something fundamental because it's not working. I have changed the action name to partOneAction() in the index controller of the user module. I expected to reach it at /user/index/part-one but I'm still getting the user/index/index action.

Comment: I don't understand how it works, in my default module IndexController (application/modules/default/IndexController) I put a testAction() and can access it by /index/test, but if I put testAction() into an other module controller (eg, application/modules/user/IndexController) I cannot access the action from /users/index/test. What am I missing?

Comment: post your application.ini and bootstrap. I think that its a configuration error.
guesses: resources.modules = [] is maybe missing from your ini, possibly an autoloader configured wrong, or a default controller issue... but i'll see once i get up in there

Comment: I raised another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106841/zend-framework-module-routes-accessing-actions) specifically about the routing once I had changed the names of actions to disclude digits. It turns out that my ACL check plugin was both wrong, and did not include a resource that was being requested by the auth user.