# Zend framework module routes - accessing actions

Tags: zend-framework

I have modules as follow:

```
modules
    default
        controllers
            IndexController

    user
        controllers
            IndexController
```

If I put an action in the default IndexController called testAction() I can run that action at /index/test or default/index/test as expected.

If I put the same action in user IndexController and try and access it at user/index/test this fails to run testAction(). Instead it run indexAction() that is in the same controller. Why does it do that?

Extra info: I have an ini file located at application/configs/application.ini and the contents of it are:

```
[production]
phpSettings.date.timezone = 'Europe/Belfast'
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

;;namespaces

;site-wide namespaces
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Plugin_"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Helper_"

;form validators
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Validate_"

;modules
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Users_"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Admin_"

;storage adapters
resources.db.adapter = mysqli
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = 
resources.db.params.dbname = vi

;modules
;resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules = ""

;layouts
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"
resources.layout.layout = master

;routes

; /home route
resources.router.routes.home.route = /home
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.module = default           
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.controller = index
resources.router.routes.home.defaults.action = index        

; /content route
resources.router.routes.static-content.route = /content/:page              
resources.router.routes.static-content.defaults.module = default           
resources.router.routes.static-content.defaults.controller = static-content
resources.router.routes.static-content.defaults.action = display 


;resources.frontController.plugins.CheckHasAccess = "Plugin_AccessCheck"


[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

[development : testing]
```

I am running the application in development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I totally forgot something... I had a ACL plugin running preDispatch that was adding some routing rules! This is a fragment of the code that caused the problem:

```
    if (! $acl->isAllowed($role, $resouce, $action)) {
        $request->setModuleName('default')
                ->setControllerName('auth')
                ->setActionName('login');
    } else {
        // if already logged in as user..
        $request->setModuleName('user')
                ->setControllerName('index')
                ->setActionName('index');
    }
```

So you see, if the user was logged in they had no choice but to end up in the user/index/index action! Hope this saves someone else the same frustration.

Comment: Also... don't forget to add any new Resource to your ACL!

Answer (score 0):

```
resources.modules = ""
```

should be

```
resources.modules = []
```